# JsonMediaTypeFormatter trying to deserialise a property with IgnoreDataMember attribute

Tags: json, deserialization, asp.net-web-api, circular-reference

I have a JSON string such as:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "Username": "mrdan",
  "Email": "mrdan@hotmale.co.uk",
  "Roles": [
    {
      "$id": "2",
      "Name": "Super Admin",
      "Users": [
        {
          "$ref": "1"
        }
      ],
      "Permissions": [
        {
          "$id": "3",
          "Name": "UserSave",
          "Roles": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "2d9a1268-6e53-4749-89f6-59ec0132e737"
        },
        {
          "$id": "4",
          "Name": "UserView",
          "Roles": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            },
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "Name": "Call Centre Manager",
              "Users": [
                {
                  "$id": "6",
                  "Username": "mrdan2",
                  "Email": "mrdan2@hotmale.co.uk",
                  "Roles": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "5"
                    }
                  ],
                  "Id": "579a0c65-26f6-4be5-aa78-72e1cd76ba11"
                }
              ],
              "Permissions": [
                {
                  "$ref": "4"
                }
              ],
              "Id": "f44702ef-03b0-4694-afcf-dc79c6826938"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "69c9a26b-0524-4b71-9675-5f167d2a9afc"
        },
        {
          "$id": "7",
          "Name": "UserDelete",
          "Roles": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            }
          ],
          "Id": "f4310d1e-1888-4917-a1de-e3f63f77a88a"
        }
      ],
      "Id": "c5f10adc-1d46-424e-afab-584cc0a8375c"
    }
  ],
  "Id": "45fa847e-ceae-4fbb-b1cc-a42dfeb53c72"
}
```

... that I want to send to the WebAPI action.  That JSON is what I get after loading a user with all the juicy circular references, I have:

```
config.Formatters.Add(
    new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
         SerializerSettings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings()
         {
              PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
              ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize
         }
    }
);
```

... in my startup for WebAPI, and this works fine on the way down to the client.  (I haven't tested it client side yet, I'm using RESTClient for Firefox at the moment for testing.)

Now, the problem I have is when I send that data back to the server.  My controller function is:

```
[Route("api/User")]
[HttpPost]
[OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
public User Save([FromBody]User user)
```

Now, everything works when I send a user without any circular references, it works when I send anything without circular references for that matter.

The symptom is that it hangs at the point of deserialisation.  I've tested that a custom httphandler is able to deserialise it from the json string into a User object, with all the circular references intact, so why isn't it doing it for the action I have?

If you need more info just let me know, this is really frustrating me as I can't debug it :(

## EDIT

I'm deserialising into POCOs like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class User : ServerEntityBase<User>
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    [Associated]
    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public override Expression<Func<IUpdateConfiguration<User>, object>> SavingObjectGraph
    {
        get
        {
            return map => map.AssociatedCollection(u => u.Roles);
        }
    }

}
```

What's strange is during the deserialisation the Get of the SavingObjectGraph property is actually called.  I don't know what's calling it, and I'd like it not to be.  During debugging, if I skip over the Get call it actually deserialises successfully and enters my Save action with the User as parameter.

Any ideas how I can stop the call to the Get?  And better yet, what's causing it to be called to begin with?

## EDIT 2

Here's the top part of the stacktrace for when the Get gets called, now the question is how do I ignore this property from the "metadata provider" :)  Getting there!

```
   at UKStainedGlass.Business.Entities.User.get_SavingObjectGraph()
   at GetSavingObjectGraphFromUser(Object )
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.Providers.AssociatedMetadataProvider`1.<>c__DisplayClass3.<GetMetadataForPropertiesImpl>b__0()
   at System.Web.Http.Metadata.ModelMetadata.get_Model()
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)
   at System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsyncCore(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, HttpParameterDescriptor paramFromBody, Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsyncCore(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally fixed this!

Turns out the clue was in the stack trace.  There's a validation process that occurs in WebAPI for model binding, and somewhere amongst that process there's a call to something called `ShouldValidateType(Type type)`.  That function was returning true for my SavingObjectGraph property, which in turn was causing an infinite loop of User to Role to User, etc.

I had to change two places to sort this out, first off, subclass the `class DefaultBodyModelValidator`, overriding its function `public override bool ShouldValidateType(Type type)` to return false when looking at my SavingObjectGraph property.  Like this:

```
public class CustomBodyModelValidator : DefaultBodyModelValidator
{
    public override bool ShouldValidateType(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Expression<>))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.ShouldValidateType(type);
    }
}
```

Then, register that on the services for my WebAPI, like this:

```
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // Configure Web API for self-host. 
        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        Register(config);

        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IBodyModelValidator), new CustomBodyModelValidator());

        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Problem solved!  I've forgotten where I found the answer I'm afraid :(  But it turns out reading stack traces can help ;)